# Python - Multiprocessing slows down gradually?

Tags: python

I recently started learning about multiprocessing in python and made this code to test it. So I have around `1300` csv files which I simply want to open and then save it to a folder with multiprocessing to test the speed. The issue here is that, the first `600-700` files are processed and saved in less than 10 seconds but the next `600-700` files takes more than 1 minute. I am really not sure why its happening. I have 8 cores and 16 gb ram in my system. Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import os,time
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np


def csv_processing(p):
    final_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['File_name', 'col'])
    for file in p :

        url = 'E:\\Ashish\\Market\\Data\\Processed GFDL_options\\Bank Nifty\\Intraday\\'
        output = 'E:\\Testing\\'
        df = pd.read_csv(url +file)
        
        df.to_csv(output+file)
        
def split_list_into_prcessess(main_list, req_process):
    index_freq = round(.5 + len(main_list)/req_process)
    splitted_list = [main_list[r*index_freq:(r+1)*index_freq] for r in range(req_process)]
    return [x for x in splitted_list if len(x)>0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    processes = []
    all_files = os.listdir('E:\\Ashish\\Market\\Data\\Processed GFDL_options\\Bank Nifty\\Intraday\\')
    print(len(all_files))
    data = split_list_into_prcessess(all_files,os.cpu_count())
    print(data)
    print(len(data))

    for t in data:
        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=csv_processing,args=(t,))
        p.start()
        processes.append(p)
    for l in processes:
        l.join()
    end_time = time.time()
    time_took = end_time - start_time
    print(time_took)
```

Comment: You should consider using threading instead of multiprocessing for I/O based operations. It was designed for it.

Comment: Contrary to popular belief multiprocessing **does not** automagically make things faster. In particular if you have HDD (instead of SSD) then reads and writes to disk are hard to parallelize. Modern disks however are quite sophisticated beasts, they have their own caches (plus there is OS and even Python cache). One possible explanation why everything slows down after 600-700 files is because you've reached the limit of all those caches and now things have to physically touch the disk with possible fsync.

Comment: Thanks for the answer freakish. I am using SSD. I doubt if its because of caches or not because I tried lengthy as well as small codes ( ranging from 1 minute to 1 hour time to complete ). The pattern of speed is the same. Initially, its very fast but then it slows down in every case